# Redirect on asynchronous Call back with AngularJS in Ionic mobile app

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I  have a mobile app created with Ionic and angularJS.In the app i'm using websql database to save data locally in device.when call my function(which is with a callback) i need move to another page(homepage).this is not happening with callback.can someone help me to figure this out.(*Im using apprey to build my application*)

Below is my  javascript function with call back function as websql is asynchronous by its nature.

```
var logbool;
ValidateUserLocalCookie(success,function(isLogged)
{

    console.log("Logged"+isLogged);


    **Apperyio.navigateTo("Home", {});///---this function should redirect to home**
});
```

and below is the websql function.

```
function ValidateUserLocalCookie(success,callbackFunc)
{
logbool=false;
    db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
    db.transaction(function(tx)
    { 
        var boole=false;
     tx.executeSql('select * from Userlog;',[],function(tx,table){
              console.log(table.rows.length);
              if(table.rows.length>0){

                     logbool=true;
        callbackFunc(logbool);
              }
              else{

                   logbool=false;
   callbackFunc(logbool);
              }


     });

    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ionic apps use the ui-router. Leverage that. You should have a list of states predefined in your router code.

Once that's done, simply inject the $state service into your controller. Inside of the callback, use it to set your state. Here is some code that does something similar.

```
function saveClass() {
  $log.log('Saving class.');

  ClassService.save(vm.class)
    .then(function () {
      $state.go('tabsController.classes');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      $log.log(err);
    });
}
```

My ClassService calls an asynchronous database function, which I have exposed as a promise. You can also use a callback. Upon completion of the save, I call `$state.go(<state-name>);` In the event of an error, I remain on the same page.

Comment: thank you for your reply Im really new to ionic apps and angular.let me try and let you know.

Comment: If you can use a promise instead of a callback, your life will improve immensely. :)